# Crop a big image into several small size pictures using GIMP 2.10.10?

Tags: gimp

## Crop a big image into several small size pictures using GIMP 2.10.10?

I tried the steps suggested in this forum to do the above. Iam not able to find this one working for recent GIMP 2.10 tool. I tried

`1) Image > Guides > New Guides (by Percent) at 25% 50% 75% horizontal and vertical resp.`    This is doable in GIMP 2.10

`2)  Apply Image > Transform > Guillotine` to slice into sub-images

I am not able to find **Guillotine** under **image/transform**. Where did this move to in GIMP 2.10?

Do we need to do this slicing differently in GIMP 2.10?

How do I bring the sliced pieces to one canvas?

I tried the steps showed in youtude video for GIMP 2.8, but those steps are not working for GIMP 2.10.

Thanks for your guidance.

Answer (score 2):

In 2.10 the "Guillotine" is "Slice using guides".

If you want to save/export (and later reload) your image in regular same-size sub-images (aka "tiles") then it can be simpler/faster to use the [`ofn-tiles` script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gimp-tools/files/scripts/).